# postgresql: extract multiple values from Char Varying field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a field in PostgreSQL of type character varying []
stored here is sector, some customers have no data, others have 1 to many sectors which ends up looking like this

```
**Customer**  ABC        
**Sector** ,Exh: Food Trade,Exh: Beverage Trade,Evt: Sporting
```

does any one know how I could query this out per value? to give me the unique values per customer

```
**Customer** ABC **sector** Exh:Food Trade,
**Customer** ABC **sector** Exh:Beverage Trade
**Customer** ABC **Sector** Evt:Sporting
```

Comment: I don't understand how exactly the data is stored in that column. Sample data is better presented as a "table like" display (e.g. copy & paste from a `psql` output` See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables. Or even better: create a little fiddle that sets up the table and some sample data, e.g. here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`unnest`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html).

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE t (customer text, sector text[]);
INSERT INTO t VALUES 
('ABC',string_to_array(',Exh: Food Trade,Exh: Beverage Trade,Evt: Sporting',','));
```

Query

```
SELECT customer, unnest(sector) FROM t;
 customer |       unnest        
----------+---------------------
 ABC      | 
 ABC      | Exh: Food Trade
 ABC      | Exh: Beverage Trade
 ABC      | Evt: Sporting
(4 Zeilen)
```

**Edit**: Getting rid of empty elements using a [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html) (see comments)

```
WITH j AS (
SELECT customer, unnest(sector) as sector FROM t 
) SELECT * FROM j WHERE sector <> '';

 customer |       sector        
----------+---------------------
 ABC      | Exh: Food Trade
 ABC      | Exh: Beverage Trade
 ABC      | Evt: Sporting
(3 Zeilen)
```

Comment: aha I think that is it :), an example field has ",Exh: Food Trade,Exh: Beverage Trade," which un nested gives me a blank value for the first result, but then I do get exh: food trade and exh beverage trade in separate rows! why would I get the first row blank? is it the leading comma?

Comment: it's because the first element of your array is empty. You string begins with a `,`